# in UITableView first entry and last entry switching record data when loading from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am developing an app that will display data from server in a parallax type `UITableView`, and here is my code. Everything is loading great, but `cell` data(image, etc) keep switching from one `cell` to another.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self hasInternet];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    [self loadData];
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self scrollViewDidScroll:nil];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self loadData];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
}
- (void) loadData{
    name = @"name";
    email = @"email";
    thumbnail = @"thumbnail";
    myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL.php"]];
    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {
        NSString *title_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"fname"];
        NSString *title_data2 = [dataDict objectForKey:@"lname"];
        NSString *fulname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", title_data, title_data2];
        NSString *emAil = [dataDict objectForKey:@"email"];
        NSString *thumbnail_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"img"];
        thumbnail_data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://URL/upload/%@",thumbnail_data];
        dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: fulname, name, emAil, email, thumbnail_data, thumbnail, nil];
        [myObject addObject:dictionary];
    }
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return myObject.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"parallaxCell";
    JBParallaxCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell=[[JBParallaxCell alloc]initWithStyle:
              UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSDictionary *tmpDict = [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSMutableString *text;
    text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpDict objectForKeyedSubscript:name]];
    NSMutableString *mail;
    mail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpDict objectForKeyedSubscript:email]];
    NSMutableString *images;
    images = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",[tmpDict objectForKey:thumbnail]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tmpDict objectForKey:thumbnail]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tmpDict objectForKey:thumbnail]];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.parallaxImage.image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
        });
    });
    cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",text];
    cell.subtitleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",mail];
    return cell;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSArray *visibleCells = [self.tableView visibleCells];    
    for (JBParallaxCell *cell in visibleCells) {
        [cell cellOnTableView:self.tableView didScrollOnView:self.view];
    }
}
```

When I compile it, it shows all my data but then keep switching from one cell to another. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Side note: While loading asynchronously is a good thing, you need to check if it's still the appropriate content to set on that cell, or you will populate a cell that should be used for different content now (reuse).

Answer (score 0):

Because UITableView reuse the cell so when you scroll down or up the previous cell which is gone from your tableview bound is reuse. but it's image view has an image when it use last time so you have to clear first the imageview.
so put this line

```
cell.parallaxImage.image = nil;
```

Before the dispatch queue

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: did that but no difference still the same problem. Thanks for your ans.

Comment: can you explain your problem elaborately?

Comment: you have another problem also in cell = [UITableViewCell alloc].
it will be [[JBParallaxCell alloc]init]

Comment: problem the that after loading data in uitableview from server records keep switching from one cell to another by themselves.

Comment: did you change the cell alloc init?

Comment: i post another code for you to save the images then show

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59498/discussion-between-bhaskar-and-user2966615).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code it will save the images in document directry and then show it.
please change the variable name.

```
NSString *imageURL = [[matcheListArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"thumbnail_image"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
NSArray *seperate = [[[matcheListArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"thumbnail_image"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[seperate objectAtIndex:seperate.count-1]];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MyFolder"];
NSError *error;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
NSString *getImagePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fileName]];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
if ([img isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
    //Set Downloaded Image
    [cell.matchUserImageView setImage:img];
}
else {
    if ([[ValidationString sharedManager] isNullString:[[matcheListArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"thumbnail_image"]] == YES) {
        //Set Default Image
        [cell.matchUserImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo_icon.png"]];
    }
    else{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            NSArray *seperate = [[[matcheListArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"thumbnail_image"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
            NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[seperate objectAtIndex:seperate.count-1]];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // Update the UI
                [cell.matchUserImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MyFolder"];
                NSString *savedImagePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fileName]];
                [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what is ValidationString in "if ([[ValidationString sharedManager] isNullString:[[matcheListArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"thumbnail_image"]] == YES)"